# concatenating literal double quotation marks in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to perform a vlookup on vba to return me the value of apple

```
 Sub test()
    Range("A1").Value = "=VLOOKUP(apple,B4:C8,2,0)"
End Sub
```

I have tried this as well

```
  Sub test()
    Range("A1").Value = "=VLOOKUP(" & "apple"& ",B4:C8,2,0)"
End Sub
```

My point is I want the apple to be written with the double quotation mark, but no matter what I do I cant seem to do it. tried the tilde key as well for literal representation of double quotation , but not working. help appreciated.

Comment: `Range("A1").Value = "=VLOOKUP(""apple"",B4:C8,2,0)"`

Comment: Scott thank you so much! I been trying this for so long and you answered it so quickly!! Brilliant!

Answer (score 0):

using chr(34) will do the job

```
Sub test()
    Range("A1").Value = "=VLOOKUP(" & Chr(34) & "apple" & Chr(34) & ",B4:C8,2,0)"
End Sub
```